# ng generate component dont result when run serve

Tags: angularjs

iam add new  ng generate component user-item

this code user-item.component.ts
We started to use the AngularJS in the project but when run serve dont show result in page .whats problem

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-item',
  templateUrl: 'user-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['user-item.component.css']
})

export class UserItemComponent implements OnInit {
    name: string;
    constructor() {
    this.name = 'test';
    }

    ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

user-item.component.html

```
   <p>
      user-item works!
    </p>
```

this code  app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UserItemComponent } from './user-item/user-item.component';
import { UserListComponent } from './user-list/user-list.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserItemComponent,
    UserListComponent,


  ],
  imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, UserItemComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

index.html

```
<body>
    <app-user-item></app-user-item>
    --
    <app-user-list></app-user-list>
    --
  <!--<app-root></app-root>-->
    -----

</body>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what console error is coming?

Comment: thanks iam sloved this problem .